# How to find annotated classes in OSGi bundle

Tags: java, jaxb, osgi

My applications has several bundles, which contain JAXB annotated classes and service bundle, which is responsible for `JAXBContext` creation.

The service bundle registers `BundleListener` and capture lifecycle events, but the problem is that I don't know how to retreive annotated classes from the `org.osgi.framework.Bundle` object. Adding entry with classes into `MANIFEST.MF` and `Bundle.loadClass(..)` will solve my problem, but finding classes by annotation seems more clear solution for me.

Do you have any idea how I can find annotated classes ?

I think I have to scan the `jar` file for `.class` resources with

```
Enumeration<?> classes = bundle.findEntries("/", "*.class", true)
```

and load them with `Bundle.loadClass(...)`. Do you think that there is going to any performance issues with this approach?

Comment: Look into keywird 'classpath scanner', but be aware that in OSGi environments bundles do come and go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly do you mean by 'classpath scanner' ? Do you mean Waving ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching the bundle with `Bundle.findEntries` does not search the Bundle-Classpath. You need to use the new [`BundleWiring.listResources`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWiring.html#listResources%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) api.

Comment: BundleWiring starts with OSGi version 4.3. What about older versions?

Comment: For OSGi versions before 4.3, you will need to write a lot of code to do the Bundle-Classpath handling yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/extcos/; while its focus is on component scanning, I think it may be able to cover your use case. Note that annotations are optional in JAXB - that is, a class can be used by JAXB without being annotated.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [reflections project](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/). Its [collect pre scanned metadata](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/wiki/UseCases#collect_pre_scanned_metadata) feature also could be useful.